# CSS is not aggregated anymore - how to debug?

Tags: 6, theming

On a rather complex Drupal 6 site (multi domain etc.) CSS files are not aggregated anymore and CSS style definitions appear directly inside the HTML pages.  The output of ´drupal_get_css´ is ok, but when I installed the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](http://drupal.org/project/advagg) module, I see that the module reports the aggregated css files as Missing files.  But when these files are opened manually, they are ok.  The problem itself is not related to the the advagg-module, I only enabled it for debug reasons.

I have not switched themes on the site affected, but I have been playing around with a new theme (mobile jquery) and a correcponding jquerymobile module on a different module from the same installation.  I do not currently think, that the problem has been caused by this module.

I guess the problem is caused by some module weights, but I am having trouble debugging the theming process.  I am looking for help, where I should start debugging, why the aggregated CSS files are not used.

**Update:**
I have edited `drupal_add_css` to default to not preprocess files.  The difference is, that each css-block is inserted in a seperate style statement, whereas right now, only a single aggregated CSS style statement is generated.  So I am really tryng to find out, why I am ending up with the long css style definition, instead of a link to the aggregated stylesheet.

Comment: Only CSS Files added with `drupal_add_css` will be aggregated.

Comment: @kantu yes thank you, I should have been clearer about that.  I am of course using drupal_add_css and the aggregation was working until recently, obviously except parts where explicitely specified not to be included in the aggregate file.  Now the aggregate files are generated, but they are not used inside the generated HTML pages.  Instead the complete CSS data is included in the pages.

Comment: If you disable advagg, and enable JS and CSS optimization on admin/settings/performance, do you still have the problem?

Comment: @MPD yes, the problem occured before enabling advagg and persists after disabling and uninstalling it.

Comment: So you edited core and now something weird is happening?

Comment: @MPD No, I have not "hacked" anything.  I am debugging a problem by trying to narrow it down where it occurs and I am asking for help in debugging it.  My problem is that drupal_get_css initially returns the correct information into the the style section of the theme variables, but it is probably overwritten by some preprocess functions.  I am asking where I could systemetically find the relevant hooks.

Answer (score 1):

I am extremely sorry, but I have found out that the problem was not caused by Drupal.  It seems that the a proxy has been installed by the ISP that automatically compresses pages and rewrites stylesheets to be included into the page directly.

The pages work correctly when being fetched via other networks.

Comment: Interesting and good job tracking this down.  Was this a normal ISP or a mobile carrier?  Broadband or dial-up?  I have only heard of mobile carriers doing this.